# Could not found load model total/subtotal OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart

Suddenly I started to recieve the below error when tring to access mysite.com after installing opencart. I kindly request your help on how to solve this ...

```
Notice: Error: Could not load model total/sub_total! in /home/xxxxx/public_html/system/engine/loader.php on line 37
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to try :

1. Check whether this file exists: `catalog\model\total\sub_total.php`.
2. Verify the file permission of `catalog\model\total\sub_total.php`.

Comment: the above files does not exists. Do I need to check in opencart?

Comment: those files exists in default opencart installation. you might have missed it. please download those files and add it.

Comment: ok, I will do that. Does this make my actual site up and running? I am curious to know of why opencart is creating problem to my actual website.

Comment: You've not given us any information regarding your actual site. The answer i posted here may fix the error related to opencart installation.

Comment: Sure I will do once try it. Hopefully it will fix. But again, why opencart is creating problem to my actual website?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48330/discussion-between-doubledecker-and-sankar-v)

Comment: sorry.. i can't be available on chat now. i'll let you know once i'm available.. 'why opencart is creating problem to my actual website?' - i've told you that we've no idea about your websites, the only information provided by you is the error message.